# Merging split files on remote machine

Tags: python, merge, zip

**Goal:** Use Python to map to a remote directory and merge eleven split files into one output named kb4577066.zip

**Intended Result:** Merging of all eleven split files into kb4577066.zip

**Actual Result:** ReturnValue = 0 is returned with no kb4577066.zip created.

**List of Archive Files:**

- kb4577066.zip.001
- kb4577066.zip.002
- kb4577066.zip.003
- kb4577066.zip.004
- kb4577066.zip.005
- kb4577066.zip.006
- kb4577066.zip.007
- kb4577066.zip.008
- kb4577066.zip.009
- kb4577066.zip.010
- kb4577066.zip.011

**Python Source:**

```
kb4577066_folder = r'C:\\Temp\\WindowsPatchesTemp\\KB4577066\\'
os.system(r"wmic /node:10.96.192.86 /user:username /password:password process call create 'cmd.exe /c copy /B kb4577066_folder\kb4577066.zip.* KB4577066.zip'")
```

I can run the following command on the remote machine to achieve the desired result.

```
copy /B kb4577066_folder\kb4577066.zip.* KB4577066.zip
```

I'm new to Python and believe that my issue may lie with the wildcard (*) that I attempting to use. I'm not sure if regular expressions or glob would be the proper solution or if anyone can recommend a better solution.